# Android studio changing the package name

Tags: android-studio

I am having problem with changing my Android package name.
First i refactored the package name and everything works fine, but the package name inside the build.gradle (app) stay the same with the old package name. 
When change the name and sync it, it gives me the following error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About **google-services.json**

if you have this line in your app level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this plugin tries to find **google-services.json** in your app module directory. if you are not using google play services ( like gcm, firebase, maps ) then you can remove this plugin in your gradle.

if you are using play services, you need to be sure you have this configuration file and this configuration file must include your application's package name. in your error picture, open google-services.json and look it does not include your package name.

Comment: Thank you. actually i was using Firebase in the past i guess this is the solution.